# Displaying custom dialog modal for route change confirmation ( using history.listenBeforeUnload )

Tags: reactjs, transition

When refreshing the page or navigating away from the site (aka losing temporary storage), I need to show the user a confirmation dialog box telling him that he will lose all unsaved data.
He can either choose to continue navigating or to cancel the transition, as expected.

I am handling this using the below code:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const history = useBeforeUnload(createHistory)();

  history.listenBeforeUnload(() => {
    confirm('You will lose all unsaved information, proceed?');
  });
}
```

This works fine, however, as per default, ReactJS uses window.confirm and others ( see: https://github.com/reactjs/history/issues/14 ) to display a confirmation dialog box.

What I have to do is to replace this box with a custom modal for confirmation.
Or at least to change its styling; heavily.

Now, I know some amount of customisation is possible through using `getUserConfirmation`  ( https://github.com/reactjs/history/blob/master/docs/ConfirmingNavigation.md )

I'm unsure how to use the getUserConfirmation to customise my message dialog box, if this is possible, or how this should be done.

I've also seen alternatives like http://bootboxjs.com/, unsure if this is a proper way to go.

Does anyone know how should I go about this & how much customisation is possible?

Comment: My 2 cents are using a bootbox or Sweet alert (http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)